# htaccess rewrite. Serve .php file when .gif is accessed

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic-image-generation

I have a dynamic image, which I wish to serve looking like a static image.

e.g. Current url of the image is

```
http://site.co.uk/media/dynamicImage.php
```

I wish for the image to be accessed using

```
http://site.co.uk/media/dynamicImage.gif
```

How do I use .htaccess to serve the dynamicImage.php file when dynamicImage.gif is accessed?

Please note that I don't want to rewrite ALL files in a folder as per this example: [Apache - rewrite images to php file with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925567/apache-rewrite-images-to-php-file-with-htaccess), I just want to rewrite the files I specify.

Comment: Do you want to be specifying specific file names or specific file extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?media/image.gif$ /media/image.php [L]
```

You can create as many of those `RewriteRules` as you need, for each specific image. This makes it so when someone requests `http://site.co.uk/media/image.gif`, they are actually being served the contents at `/media/image.php`.

If you need to keep this all within the `media` directory, e.g. you already have some rules in the media directory's htaccess file, you can modify the rules to look like:

```
RewriteRule ^image.gif$ image.php [L]
```