# Changing .PHP do .PNG

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic image script that shows user info on an image using this tag

`<img src="http://domain.com/dynamicimage.php" />`

Any way to change the `.PHP` to `.PNG` using .hatccess ?

Comment: Change it in the source of the HTML or make the server respond to a request for `dynamicimage.png`? Why bother? File extensions don't matter in URLs, the Content-Type does.

Comment: Well would it work, because if I try to use this link in a forum signature It show's me "bla bla bla image extension not allowed".That's why I need some help

Comment: So you want to rewrite only `dynamicimage.php` to `dynamicimage.png` or you want to rewrite all `*.php` to `.png` ?

Comment: Yes just the dynamicimage.php to .PNG

Comment: `file.php?i=image.png`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update the .htaccess for this. 
If you don't mind the .php extension in the src attribute, you simple make sure the php script generates the correct header for the png content. For example:

```
 header('Content-Length: '.strlen($imgesrcstring));
 header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

If you do mind the .php extension, you will need to put something into .htaccess for rewrite settings so that any request to dynamicimage.png is handled by dynamicimage.php

In that case please have a look at this question:

[Apache - rewrite images to php file with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925567/apache-rewrite-images-to-php-file-with-htaccess)